# Error 500 al mandar archivo al servidor SpringBoot-Angular2

Tags: angular, spring-boot

estoy intentando mandar un excell del Angular2 al SpringBoot.

HTML:

```
  <form #fileLoad="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addExcell()">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file"  class="form-control" (change)="fileChange($event)"  accept=".xlsx">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline btn-block">Add</button>
   </form>
```

Component.ts

Selecciono un excel->

```
fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      let file: File = fileList[0];
      this.formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
    }
  }
```

Doy click en enviar ->

```
 addExcell() {
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/ml/insert";
    this.service.sendFile(url, this.formData).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
```

En los servicios configuro las cabeceras y lo envío:

```
sendFile(url, myFile) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    return this.http2.post(url,   myFile , { headers: headers });
  }
```

Y para recogerlo con SpringBoot:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = { "/ml" })
@CrossOrigin
public class MyFile{

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/insert" , headers = "Content-Type= multipart/form-data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @ResponseBody
        public String insert(@RequestBody MultipartFile multipart) {

            System.out.println("file" + multipart);
            return "SpringBoot";

        }
}
```

error SpringBoot:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2869) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Error en el html :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba a comentar esta línea: `headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');`

Comment: @PabloLozano esa línea ya estaba puesta.

Comment: Comentar: convertir en comentario. Quería decir que la quitases

Comment: lo quito del angular o de SpringBoot ?

Comment: De Angular: creo que el problema se soluciona si dejas que ese header se meta automáticamente

Comment: No da error el angular, recibe el "ok Status 200" del SpringBoot, pero en el SpringBoot, obtengo que el fichero null

Comment: podemos entrar a al chat ?? (No sé crearlo)

Comment: En el pie de la página de SOes siempre hay un enlace al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente con la ayuda de PabloLozano se obtuvo la solución:

Angular :

```
  addExcell() {
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/ml/insert";
    this.service.sendFile(url, this.formData).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }

  fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
      let file: File = fileList[0];
      this.formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
    }
  }

 sendFile(url, myFile) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return this.http2.post(url,   myFile , { headers: headers });
  }
```

SpringBoot:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/insert", headers = "Content-Type= multipart/form-data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String insert(@RequestParam("uploadFile") MultipartFile multipart) {

        try {

            File destinationFile = new File("C:\\Users\\yo\\Desktop\\fichero.xlsx");
            multipart.transferTo(destinationFile);

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(destinationFile);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
                }

                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();

        } catch (

        Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "SpringBoot";

    }
```

Con esto se consigue mandar un Excell desde Angular2 a SpringBoot.